# How would I make it so my API is only accessible through my application (Javascript and PHP)?

Tags: javascript, php, api, security, endpoint

I'm currently creating my first API. I know how to setup all the endpoints and do what I want with them. The issue I'm having is that I don't want just anyone to be able to visit `site.com/api/example` and get data back from it. What methods/concepts are available to make sure that only my application is able to access the API. I'm going to want to POST and GET these endpoints using both Javascript and PHP.

Any help at all on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, you can't make it 100% secure since you need javascript to be able to access it (which is executed in the users browser and can be manipulated). You can make it harder for people, though, by adding some CSRF-checks.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson That raises another question. If the API is only returning data that is already getting output to the site anyway, does it really even matter if it's secure? Now, the endpoints that I'm going to want to POST to are going to need something to validate it's an authentic request from the site. I plan on posting for AJAX likes and comments with a user account or IP address.

Comment: For posting data, you should definitely use some [`CSRF`](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) protection. Regarding locking the API's down, it all depends on the data. Some sites wants to make people access any data through their site, instead of just fetching the data directly. If that isn't an issue for you, then no, you probably don't need to trying to lock it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically two solutions:

1. Application authentication: your application will be responsible for handling the authentication of your user and provide to the server evidence of a successful authentication. The implementation will vary depending on whether the authentication is done directly on the server (by provinding credentials) or indirectly (it would then provide to the server an authentictaion token). Some keywords: oAuth, JWT, LDAP
2. [Client-side TLS certificate](https://techblog.bozho.net/tls-client-authentication/): the server will request from your app to present a TLS certificate in order to set up the TLS tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

Here's two options:

1. Don't let anyone know you're using an API. Only call the API from server side, let the API only listen to requests from your server's IP. Direct Javascript API calls to your server that forwards them to the API and sends the (perhaps even filtered) API response object to client side.
2. API authentication in combination with ACL (Access Control List). Use oAuth or JWT to generate an access token that you send with each request. Through the ACL you can vary the output, based on which user is doing the request. Perhaps Javascript requests are responded to with limited public data, while responses to your server side requests can contain data you may need for processing, but don't want to share publicly.

Personally I use a combination of both. JWT authentication and never letting Javascript send requests directly, I always validate these server side before forwarding them to the API (if response is not cached on the server already).